# /imu: VN: Permission denied

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to connect an imu VN-100 Rugged to ROS via [this package](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_vn_100). But, I get the following output in my terminal:

```
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13597]
started core service [/rosout]
process[imu-2]: started with pid [13607]
[ INFO] [1464357306.167245353]: Sync out rate: 20
[ INFO] [1464357306.748363389]: Connected to device at /dev/ttyUSB0
[ INFO] [1464357306.765977143]: Default serial baudrate: 115200
[ INFO] [1464357306.766011559]: Set serial baudrate to 921600
[ INFO] [1464357307.776820987]: Connected to device at /dev/ttyUSB0
[ INFO] [1464357307.783369148]: New serial baudrate: 921600
[ INFO] [1464357307.788441741]: Fetching device info.
[ INFO] [1464357307.793557811]: Model number: VN-100T-CR
[ INFO] [1464357307.798613813]: Hardware revision: 7
[ INFO] [1464357307.803668418]: Serial number: 0100017300
[ INFO] [1464357307.808746557]: Firmware version: 2.0.0.0
[ INFO] [1464357307.808777854]: Set Synchronization Control Register (id:32).
[ INFO] [1464357307.837879233]: /imu: VN: Permission denied
[imu-2] process has finished cleanly
```

I tried to change the baud rate of /dev/ttyUSB0 to something else according to the acceptable baud rates in [this link](http://www.vectornav.com/docs/default-source/documentation/vn-100-documentation/UM001.pdf?sfvrsn=10). However, I get the same result each time.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236809//imu:-vn:-permission-denied/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[link text](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_vn_100/pull/11)
This is what solved it for me.  Now this is a setting you can change in the launch file itself.

---

Originally posted by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) with karma: 151 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0